# What is the difference between <%: and <%= in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, tags

I can't find this info anywhere. Probably because Google is ignoring the keywords. Is there a difference between using `<%:` and `<%=` in your aspx page? They seem interchangeable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`<%: %>` is [a new thing in ASP.NET MVC 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx). It is the same as `<%= Html.Encode("Text") %>`. It is recommended to always use `<%: %>` unless you have some specific reason to not do so (for example, you are rendering data from some file or database that's already been encoded).

Comment: Does this syntax have an equivalent form in Razor?

Answer (score 6):

The difference is :

`<%= "my <text>" %>` will output `my <text>`, which is incorrect HTML

`<%: "my <text>" %>` will output `my &lt;text&gt;`, which is better

[More details here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

@ntcolonel is right on the money. Additionally, for cases where your data has already been encoded, provide it using anything implementing `IHtmlString`. This prevents double-encoding, and allows you to *always* use `<%: %>`.

I believe that ASP.NET 4 shops should gravitate toward enforcing <%: %> by policy.

Also, the new syntax is for ASP.NET 4 in general; not necessarily just MVC, which is great news for WebForms developers.